# TensorFlow logical operation ((A == B) && (C == D)) results in "Incompatible shapes: [2] vs. [3]"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to build the following logical expression -

```
tf.logical_and(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,0), tf.argmax(y_,0)), 
                tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)), name=None)
```

But it results in the below error -

> Incompatible shapes: [2] vs. [3]

`tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,0), tf.argmax(y_,0))` and `tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))` work fine separately, the error occurs only with `tf.logical_and`. `tf.logical_and` expects boolean tensors and `tf.equal` returns boolean tensors, so all arguments are in order so not sure why it fails.

To give some context, the original code is below and I'm just trying to update `correct_prediction` to include both 0 and 1 for `tf.argmax`

UPDATE1 Start (this adds all of the variable declarations)

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)
def conv2d(x, W): return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
def max_pool_2x2(x): return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
W_conv1 = weight_variable([3, 3, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 9])
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,3,3,1])
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_conv1, [-1, 3 * 3 * 32])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
W_fc2 = weight_variable([64, 2])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([2])
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
```

UPDATE1 End (this adds all of the variable declarations)

**This is where the problem is located -**

```
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
#This works - correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,0), tf.argmax(y_,0)) . Changed it to -
correct_prediction = tf.logical_and(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,0), tf.argmax(y_,0)), 
                tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1)), 
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
train_step.run(feed_dict={x: xtrain, y_: ytrain, keep_prob: 0.5})
#In debugging mode, code breaks at the below line
print("test accuracy %g"%accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: xtest, y_: ytest, keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

How can I debug this error?

Comment: Do you think you could distill this to a simple self-contained 10 liner? That would help.

Comment: Done. I'm not proficient enough in python and tensorflow to rewrite it to be much smaller but I added the missing code in a separate section labeled "UPDATE 1". The core of the question though is why `tf.logical_and(tf.equal(...), tf.equal(...))` fails when both `tf.equal(...)` work fine by themselves. The `tf.equal` return boolean tensors and `tf.logical_and` expects boolean tensors, so why does it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem arises because `tf.equal()` is an *elementwise* operation and it returns a tensor with the same shape as its arguments. The easiest way to fix your expression is to use `tf.reduce_all()` to aggregate the results of `tf.equal()` down to a scalar before computing the `tf.logical_and()`, as follows:

```
tf.logical_and(
    tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 0), tf.argmax(y_, 0))), 
    tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))))
```